# Is using scented soap on Shabbos a problem of molid?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, smell, pesik-reisha

Is there a problem of being [molid](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Molid) reyach (causing a fragrance) in the water? I was told that it's forbidden to use Poo Pourri or Just A Drop because it makes the water have a fragrance? What about the tap water that now has the scent of the soap?
At least this sounds like a [psik reisha](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Melechet_Machshevet)?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Ariel. Suggestion - many readers, including me, are not too familiar with the terms you used. I understand the words (such as "molid"), but I am unfamiliar with the general problem that you explain and why "molid reyach" and "psik resha" is a problem on Shabbat. If you can, provide a brief description and / or links to areas where we can learn enough to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: @Ari, I hope this will answer your question: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/may-one-wash-his-hands-with-liquid-soap-on-shabbos/. Look at Scented liquid soaps, footnote 11 for your specific question, and look at the summary

Answer (score 0):

The issue of Molid Reyach in water is a machlokes Achronim

The Shaare Teshuva 128:6 says that even according to those who say putting a scent in water is prohibited on Shabbos, it is permitted if it was done before shabbos:

> עבה"ט ועיין לקמן סי' תקי"א בט"ז ומג"א ושם כתב הבה"ט מתשו' גור אריה ותשו' ח"צ סי' צ"ב ובבר"י סי' תקי"א בשם רבו בס' נחפה בכסף דבשבת יש להחמיר שלא לתת בשמים במים העומדים לרחיצה אך אם נתונים מע"ש מותר לרחוץ בהם ע"ש

The MB 128:23 also brings this machlokes:

> יש מקומות שהמנהג ששופכין שמן של ריח במים והמ"א כאן ובט"ז לקמן סימן תקי"א כתבו דאסור דמוליד ריחא והא"ר וכן הח"צ בסימן צ"ב דעתם להקל דלא שייך מוליד ריחא בזה כיון שהשמן עצמו מעורב במים. ובנתונים מע"ש ועיו"ט בודאי יש לסמוך עלייהו להקל אף דמוליד ריחא בידי הכהנים כמו שכתב בשע"ת

The only other point to consider, is perhaps in this case, it’s a psik reisha dlo nicha lei since the water goes right down the drain.